# Jenkins pull request plugin throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception

Tags: java, jenkins, pull-request

When I enable the option `Use github hooks for build triggering` in a Jenkins project and try to save, I get the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getRepository(GitHub.java:342)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRepository.initGhRepository(GhprbRepository.java:112)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRepository.getGitHubRepo(GhprbRepository.java:401)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRepository.hookExist(GhprbRepository.java:269)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbRepository.createHook(GhprbRepository.java:292)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.start(GhprbTrigger.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.start(GhprbTrigger.java:66)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.submit(AbstractProject.java:1884)
    at hudson.model.Project.submit(Project.java:230)
    at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1246)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:796)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor303.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:324)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:52)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:167)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:100)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    ... 58 more
```

I have no clue why this happens. Has anyone an idea? Building on merging  a pull requests works just fine. If I disable the option, I can save the project without any exceptions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the plugin... You should probably report this on their bug tracker.

Comment: @Tunaki,  How to resolve this error? Am using the jenkins verion 2.77.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failing method is this one and the only reason for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` can be incorrectly formatted (without `/`) or missing (empty) token:

```
public GHRepository getRepository(String name) throws IOException {
    String[] tokens = name.split("/");
    return retrieve().to("/repos/" + tokens[0] + '/' + tokens[1], GHRepository.class).wrap(this);
}
```

Here is the link to the source: https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GitHub.java

The plugin documentation provides the following example for github (and it fails for GitHub as one can see from the stacktrace):

```
remote {
    github('test-owner/test-project')
    refspec('+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*')
}
```

I suspect that `remote.github` must be in that format containing a single slash.

Comment: This isn't really an answer though. What should be OP do to solve the problem? This sounds more like a commentary intended to the plugin developers.

Comment: I guess checking the tokens would be the next step, what do you think?

Comment: @Tunaki But I agree with you that it is a bug in the plugin as it should not permit it go that far with incorrect credentials and failing with a runtime exception.

Comment: @OlegSklyar thanks for your answer. It is working now. The project url was wrong. It should be: `https://github.com/org/repo` and not only `https://github.com/org` thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, but do file a bug report if you can to the plugin developers -- AIOOBE is of the same level as NPE, should be properly handled by the code: checked or rethrown with sensible messages